# Cloudinary responsive images only displaying on window size change in React using Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, cloudinary

I am serving cloudinary images responsively following this documentation:

http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_automatically_create_images_for_responsive_design#implementing_responsive_design_with_cloudinary_s_javascript_library

My index.hjs looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cloudinary-
     core/2.3.0/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var cl = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({cloud_name: "myCloudName"});
      cl.responsive();
    </script>
</body>
```

Component rendering images has this per the above documentation:

```
{this.state.images.map(function(image, i){
                return <img key={i} className="cld-responsive thumbnail"
                            data-src={image.albums.images}/>})}
```

the problem is on the initial render, the images render as 100% width with 0 height and don't appear at all. However, if I resize the window the responsive images are shown.

Do I need to move the

```
 cl.responsive();
```

to somewhere else in my code? I tried moving it into the component and triggering a state refresh with componentDidMount() but the images still don't show on re-render; only if the window is resized.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you also share the HTML part where you set the image on?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK automatically updates images on resize when they have a `responsive` attribute set on them.

Sample code:

```
<div className="image-holder">
    <Image publicId="sample" responsive>
        <Transformation width="auto" crop="scale"/>
    </Image>
</div>
```

Link to full example: https://codepen.io/eitanp461/project/editor/ZoNNkP

Note that Cloudinary's React SDK depends on `cloudinary-core` so you don't need to load it as a separate script from your `index.html`.

Comment: I was previously not using the cloudinary-react library. however one more issue is that I am unable to use a map function to create a list of  images like so:      
  `{displayImages.map(function(displayImage, i){
                                  return 
                                    <Image key={i} publicId={displayImage} responsive>
                                      <Transformation width="auto" crop="scale"/>
                                    </Image>
                                })}`

Comment: do you know of a way around this issue?

Comment: never mind, i was able to find an example to follow for my own format.